# Jquery Checking the element whether its a parent or ancestor of an element.

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to find whether an element is a parent or ancestor of other.

I have searched the jquery and found the below method. But here we cant use any java script plain object or jquery object.

```
$.contains( document.documentElement, document.body ); // true
```

How to validate? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the number of children are there:

```
contains = function (parent, child) {
    if ( $(parent).find(child).length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Use this way:

```
contains("body", ".check");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) you can traverse up the DOM tree. If the length returned is greater than 0 then a parent/ancestor has been found.

For example:

```
if ($(".child").closest(".parent").length){
   alert("parent / ancestor found");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqactw0a/1/

Comment: This will always return true. Won't it? Can you demonstrate a place where this **doesn't alert**?

Comment: When there is no `.parent` element which is a parent of `.child`.

Comment: Sorry, I took it in a generic way. `:)`

Comment: It is probably more efficient to use `closest()` instead of `parents()`... but we are talking about tiny amounts of performance here, so it's not much of an issue

Comment: Just for reference, [here is a performance test](http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-parents-check)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to select the element, for example

```
if ( $('#parent .child').length ) {
  // the element #parent is a parent or ancestor of .child
} else {
  // the element #parent is NOT a parent or ancestor of .child
}
```

Comment: what if the children element has no child class ?

Comment: lenght will be `0` which is false(ey), so this will work correctly. Maybe brush up on javascript before downvoting

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('#div1').children().length > 0) {
     alert('i'm a parent div')
}
```

The `children()` function returns that object has children or not. use can use it to check whether the element is parent or not.

Comment: would'nt this just check if a element has **any** children, not if a element has a specified child?

Comment: @atmd: before downvote, did you read the question ? whether an element is a parent or ancestor. not asking for any specific child.

Comment: I did'nt downvote, also "element is a parent or ancestor of other" suggest a specified parent and child